# Gunicorn not starting on AWS EB instance?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, gunicorn, procfile

I am deploying a Django project onto an AWS EB instance. It runs perfectly locally. When I deploy through the CLI, it generates a Procfile that contains the command to start the gunicorn server. However, it is not getting started. I can SSH into the instance, run "python manage.py runserver" or run the line from the Procfile to start gunicorn, both start the server and get things working great. However, this should happen when the project is deployed, and it is not. I do not get any errors when making migrations, running the server, or manually starting gunicorn. So why is it not starting automatically? After deploying and going to the site, it gives a 502 error.

Comment: It's likely that you need to run on 0.0.0.0 (the external IP address) because localhost 127.0.0.1 won't be externally visible to the outside internet.

Comment: @SamDolan It is externally visible when I SSH in and manually start gunicorn. I do not see anywhere in the django settings to change this. The Procfile that EB generates does not specify a port, but if i SSH in and run the Procfile code, it starts gunicorn and i can access the instance just fine. It seems to be like gunicorn is not starting on deployment, however I do not see any errors in the logs.

Comment: @JohnMichaelHayde I don't suppose you ever got to the bottom of this and can remember how you go gunicorn running automatically as part of the deployment? We're experiencing the exact same issue by the sounds of it! Thanks

Comment: @DW unfortunately I was never able to resolve the issue. This project had a very short lifecycle and I was wasting too much time, so I made a workaround that used a script to connect to the server and execute the necessary commands to start gunicorn. This script would get triggered at the end of a successful EB build process.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMichaelHayde - we managed to find the cause of the issue after looking through the systemd logs for the `web` service that runs gunicorn. Initially, `tail /var/log/web.stdout.log` gave some hints, but these contain truncated output. `journalctl -u web -n 300 --no-pager` showed us that one of environment variables was failing to be parsed correctly when systemd was starting gunicorn. Changing how we set this env variable fixed out specific issue.